# Size of download in MacPorts

Tags: macports, apt-get, package-managers

When i try to install a package through apt-get on linux, it shows me the total amount to be downloaded and the space that will be used after install. Is there a way to view this information while using macports on mac os x?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As due the nature of macports that is not possible:
Most linux distibutions provide binary packages. Macports provides what can be thought of "receipes":

Macports downloads, compiles and installs everything necessary for your installation. Therefore Macports does not provide that data, but the instruction for the system where to download them and what to do them with it.

The only thing I could suggest is that you do a 
(the default PREFIX is /opt/local/ )

```
du -sh PREFIX
sudo port install WHATEVER
du -sh PREFIX
```

and compare the used size.